# Hiding content - CSS or php conditions?

Tags: css

I know how to hide a content using CSS and php. Now, my question is which will be advisable?

**My Scenario**

I have added a footer widget (*e.g. Recent Posts*) to 4 widget sections in a WP site. But I wish to make this widget displayed in a particular page and keep it removed from rest of the site.

I tried with both the conditional php tags and also with CSS `display:none;`separately. The CSS I used is -

```
#recent-posts {
display:none;
}
.page-id-123 #recent-posts {
display:block;
}
```

Now, which will be advisable - in terms of SEO, page speed performance and usability across almost all devices.

**PS:** I just do not wish to use javascript in this case.

Thank you very much in advance.
Kalyan

Comment: in terms of SEO and pagespeed, I would advise you to prevent them from being inserted in page source ... that means removing them via PHP. That way the size of the html page the browser has to load is lower and SEO wise, there will not be so much hidden content on your page

Comment: Watch out for the typo `dispaly:block;` on the class.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. This clears my doubt.